# Regex - Escape metacharacter

Tags: regex

I learn regex these days and come accros below expression which I am struggling to understand.

*Regex* : +.*?\?

```
abcdefghlkah    ezarekjha
a       fzfehuoa
aaaaaaaaaa$avaezvr  $    + efékjhfoéu?vrezavr?vezv$
```

It matches string '**+ efékjhfoéu?**'

As I understand it, the string starts with '+' symbol literaly then any character zero or multiple times. So far I get it well. But then metacharacter '?' shows up which does not make sense to me here because it affects previous character which is '*'.

Maybe metacharacter '?' behaves differently when it comes to affecting metacharacter that is escaped which in my case is '\?'.

Is the behavior of metacharacter different in that case? Should it be placed before the metacharacter that is escpaed to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When used after a repeat character (like `{}`, `*`, `+`...), the `?` character makes it lazy, and it will match the least possible.
For instance:

- `a+?b` in `aaaabaaba` will match `[aaaab]aaba`, the least it can
- `a+b` in `aaaabaaba` will match `[aaaabaab]a`, the most it can

Answer (score 0):

The first question mark is a metacharacter, yet it does not act like a `{0,1}`. It changes the `*` wildcard from being greedy ( as much matches as possible ), to being lazy ( as few matches as possible ). The second is escaped, so it become litteraly the question mark character.

I had a hard time trying to understand your question. I hope this explication is what you are looking for.